# How to catch any exception in Anypoint studio?

Tags: exception, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I want to specify a global catch exception strategy that would catch any exception a mule app throws. Please help me.

Comment: what version are you using. remember if you are on mule 4 then it deploys the more java style of try-catch scenario. if you on more 3.x then the exception handling is very different.

Comment: Also Mule 4 uses Mule Errors instead of exceptions.